# DXF string compare

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I have the following problem, the string from the Autocad DXF file does not compare with the string in my AS3 file even though they are absolutely identical.

As a simple example

```
private function onComplete():void 
{
   myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("Drawing1.dxf"));
   myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);                 
}

private function onLoaded(e:Event):void {

myArrayOfLines = e.target.data.split(/\n/);

for(var i:uint=0;i<=myArrayOfLines.length-2;i++)
{
  GetLineCouple(i);
  if(line1 == "0" && line2 == "LINE")//comparison does not work here
 {
     //Any code
 }  
}

//to remove whitespaces
public function stripspaces(originalstring:String):String
{
   var original:Array=originalstring.split(" ");
    return(original.join(""));
}

private function GetLineCouple (index:uint):void    
{
   line1 = stripspaces(myArrayOfLines[index]);
   line2 = stripspaces(myArrayOfLines[index+1]);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might want to elaborate a bit more...

Comment: Sounds like you might have an encoding problem... Perhaps if you describe better what you're doing, how you are loading and reading this string, etc, someone might be able to help you.

Comment: Are you sure `line1` contains "0" and `line2`, "LINE" with the exact casing and no leading or trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Was not removed hyphen on the next line, and now everything works

public function stripspaces(originalstring:String):String
{
     return originalstring.replace(/\s+/g, "");
}